# Error importing from Nuget on Xamarin form project in vs 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, frameworks

When i try to import some nugets like BCL trhrow the message that you could see, I try to create a project with 4.6.1 framwork and the problem persist

[See picture and error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2TmK.png)

Comment: Please add more details and post the relevant parts of stack trace and code within your question. So you have better chances to get the necessary attention

Comment: I recently update my xamarin forms, and when i create the project, i dont know why the target framwork go to 2.0 as you see in the picture error 1
and when i try to import from nugget a bild like BCL throw the error that you see on the image error2

as you could see on the image show1 you could see that i have all the framwork versions installed

error1
![](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/ey/nm5azwu0gkv6.png "")
error2
![](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/db/cfy7m3z2w5xp.png "")
show1
![](https://us.v-cdn.net/5019960/uploads/editor/sr/tjtg41ykqq48.png "")